# When I use anchor command, I'm getting an error: no such subcommand: `+bpf` Did you mean `b`?

Tags: anchor, command, bpf

The error goes like this:

PS D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter\programs\counter-app> anchor build
BPF SDK: \?\C:\Users\Prabh.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.10.31\solana-release\bin\sdk\bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain uninstall bpf
info: uninstalling toolchain 'bpf'
info: toolchain 'bpf' uninstalled
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain link bpf \?\C:\Users\Prabh.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.10.31\solana-release\bin\sdk\bpf\dependencies\bpf-tools\rust
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: no such subcommand: `+bpf`

```
    Did you mean `b`?
```

PS D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter\programs\counter-app> rustup toolchain list -v
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default) C:\Users\Prabh.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
bpf     C:\Users\Prabh.cache\solana\v1.27\bpf-tools\rust
1.59.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc   C:\Users\Prabh.rustup\toolchains\1.59.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
PS D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter\programs\counter-app>

Comment: can you please clean up the formatting here by putting command invocations and their output in separate code blocks?  as is, this is impossible to read

Answer (score 1):

You actually can build with Windows natively!  The tools all work, but you must run from within a bash-supported shell.

Try installing Git Bash and then retrying your build from there https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Solana development isn't being supported by Windows, so it's pretty much impossible to run build-bpf command. You might need a Linux machine for that. So either :

- Get WSL (I highly recommend it, since it's pretty easy and doesn't require a lot of input) : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
- Or get a Linux partition (via Dual Boot if you want to keep using Windows)

I personally got WSL for the sake of simplicity. Either way you'll need to learn how Linux terminal works, which is pretty similar to Power Shell, but it has its own caveats. I recommend watching this video about the Linux terminal, if you want to learn more :
https://youtu.be/s3ii48qYBxA